# Simple Additive Combinatorics problem

Tags: additive-combinatorics

In Terence Tao's book, Additive Combinatorics, page 70, it says:

> For instance, if one knows that 
>    $$
>  A + B \subseteq A + X 
>  $$
>   then one can immediately
>   deduce that 
>   $$
> A + n B \subseteq A + n X 
> $$ 
>   for all $n ≥ 0$.

I'm really confused about why this could work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding $iB+(n-i-1)X$ to the first equation:

$$A+(i+1)B + (n-i-1)X\subset A+iB+(n-i)X$$

Therefore $A+nB \subset A+(n-1)B+X \subset \cdots  \subset A+nX$